# Who will hold the next God titles?

Tags: gods

I have read earlier that Lord Hanuman will be the next Brahma, Demon king Bali will be next Indra. So mostly the God names that we know are kind of titles or designation which belong to different people at different times. So, are there any other people that we know will hold a God title in future, like who will be next Lord Vishnu or Lord Shiva.

Comment: This is complex. Shaivites say Shiva is not position while Vaishnavites say Vishnu is not position while Advaitins say both are equal and not positions.

Comment: @The Destroyer, Agree with you, but my question is not specific to Lord Shiva and Lord Vishnu. I wanted to know are there any texts predictions or hints which indicate about any Gods/Demigods

Answer (score 2):

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp076.htm

> The son of Chháyá, who was called also a Manu, was denominated Sávarńi 6, from being of the same caste (Savarńa) as his elder brother, the Manu Vaivaswata. He presides over the ensuing or eighth Manwantara; the particulars of which, and the following, I will now relate. In the period in which Sávarńi shall be the Manu, the classes of the gods will be Sutapas, Amitábhas, and Mukhyas; twenty-one of each. The seven Rishis will be Díptimat, Gálava, Ráma, Kripa, Drauńi; my son Vyása will be the sixth, and the seventh will be Rishyasringa 7. The Indra will be Bali, the sinless son of Virochana, who through the favour of Vishńu is actually sovereign of part of Pátála. The royal progeny of Sávarńi will be Virajas, Arvarívas, Nirmoha, and others.

Díptimat, Gálava, Ráma, Kripa, Drauńi and Vyasa will be the next Saptarishis in Savarni Manvantara and Bali, the son of Virochana and the grandson of Prahlada will be the next Indra. Savarni Manu is the next Manu.

https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp077.htm

Parashara also tells in Vishnu Purana of the next Vyasa

> In the next Dwápara, Drauńi (the son of Drońa) will be the Vyása, when my son, the Muni Krishńa Dwaipáyana, who is the actual Vyása, shall cease to be (in that character.

> The ninth Manu will be Daksha-sávarńi 8. The Páras, Maríchigarbhas, and Sudharmas will be the three classes of divinities, each consisting of twelve; their powerful chief will be the Indra Adbhuta. Savana, Dyutimat, Bhavya, Vasu, Medhatithi, Jyotishmán, and Satya will be the seven Rishis. Dhritaketu, Driptiketu, Panchahasta, Mahámáyá, Prithuśrava, and others, will be the sons of the Manu.
>
> In the tenth Manwantara the Manu will be Brahmá-sávarńi: the gods will be the Sudhámas, Viruddhas, and Śatasankhyas: the Indra will be the mighty Śánti: the Rishis will be Havishmán, Sukriti, Satya, Apámmúrtti, Nábhága, Apratimaujas, and Satyaketu: and the ten sons of the Manu will be Sukshetra, Uttarnaujas, Harisheńa, and others.
>
> In the eleventh Manwantara the Manu will be Dharma-sávarńi: the principal classes of gods will be the Vihangamas, Kámagamas, and Nirmánaratis, each thirty in number 9; of whom Vrisha will be the Indra: the Rishis will be Niśchara, Agnitejas, Vapushmán, Vishńu, Áruni, Havishmán, and Anagha: the kings of the earth, and sons of the Manu, will be Savarga, Sarvadharma, Deváníka, and others.
>
> In the twelfth Manvantara the son of Rudra, Sávarńi, will be the Manu: Ritudhámá will be the Indra: and the Haritas, Lohitas, Sumanasas, and Sukarmas will be the classes of gods, each comprising fifteen. Tapaswí, Sutapas, Tapomúrtti, Taporati, Tapodhriti, Tapodyuti, and Tapodhana will be the Rishis: and Devaván, Upadeva, Devaśresht́a, and others, will be the Manu's sons, and mighty monarchs on the earth.
>
> In the thirteenth Manwantara the Manu will be Rauchya 10: the classes of gods, thirty-three in each, will be the Sudhámans, Sudharmans, and Sukarmans; their Indra will be Divaspati: the Rishis will be Nirmoha, Tatwadersín, Nishprakampa, Nirutsuka, Dhritimat, Avyaya, and Sutapas: and Chitrasena, Vichitra, and others, will be the kings.
>
> In the fourteenth Manvantara, Bhautya will be the Manu 11; Suchi, the Indra: the five classes of gods will be the Chákshushas, the Pavitras, Kanisht́has, Bhrájiras, and Vávriddhas: the seven Rishis will be Agnibáhu, Śuchi, Śukra, Magadhá, Gridhra, Yukta, and Ajita: and the sons of the Manu will be Uru, Gabhíra, Bradhna, and others, who will be kings, and will rule over the earth.

It lists the positions of the gods from the 8th manvantara upto the 14th manvantara. In a kalpa, there are 14 mnvantaras